# CK EDITOR gets focussed unexpectedly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, ckeditor

I have developed a chat application using jquery which uses CK EDITOR to post messages. The app works perfectly fine in firefox and IE, but in Chrome I have following issue:

CK EDITOR is focussed using mouse-cursor, then 'tab' is pressed to take focus to some other element (say some link / button);now when any key (say 'q' or 'm' etc.) is pressed, the EDITOR gets focussed automatically and gets control unexpectedly. If the user continues to type something, that text is written into the CK EDITOR text area.

But the issue is not observed if the initial focus was not put on the CK EDITOR input text area.

Someone please help me out with this issue.